# Como depurar código em python na IDE Geany?

Tags: python, linux, debug, ide

Estou aprendendo programação em python e, para isso, estou utilizando a IDE GEANY no Fedora 24. Estou adorando utilizá-la, porém não consigo depurar o meu código. Já instalei o plugin de depuração. Alguém saberia como depurar?

Comment: Qual plugin de depuração instalou?

Comment: instalei o depurador pdb e gdb

Comment: Algum problema de execução ou não aparece nada?

Comment: Ao clicar no botão Executar, para depurar, aparece uma mensagem de erro: Erro ao ler ficheiro!

Comment: Tem como por imagens ou mensagens que aparece? Fica mais explícito..

Outra maneira seria usar o pbd , mas ai seria mais manual..